# slick с постоянным слайдом

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Есть вот такой слайдер: 
[image: Слайдер]

Сделан на slick slider, переключаются они затуханием. Суть в том что нужно менять только первые 3 колонки, а 4 должна быть статичной. Объясните мне логику как это сделать. И ещё 4 блок должен затухать со всеми колонками.

**PS** Код писать не обязательно, просто объясните логику.

Answer (score 0):

А просто рядом расположить можно ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
    <style>
      .slider{
       width:600px;
       height:400px;
       overflow: hidden;
      }
      .slider .item{
       min-width:200px;
       max-width: 200px;
       height: 400px;
       background: lightblue;
       outline: 1px solid;
       margin-right: 4px;
      }

      .main{
       display: flex;
       width: 1000px;
       margin: 30px auto;
      }

      .main > .price{
       width:200px;
       height: 400px;
       background: lightblue;
       margin-left: 4px;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="main">
 <div class="slider">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
 </div>
 <div class="price">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste optio at, quisquam dolore esse consequuntur tempora placeat, voluptas. Asperiores, tempora.
 </div>
</div>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.slider').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 2,
  arrows: false,
  pauseOnHover: true,
  infinite: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 1000
}); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```